# blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload - change upload path

Tags: blueimp

I try to upload an image to my server by using **[blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)**. The path is set to `server/php` by default in `main.js` and `app.js` and the files are saved to `server/php/files/`.

However, I need to save it to another location: `fotos`

I tried to change `upload_dir` and `upload_url` in **server/php/UploadHandler.php** to `fotos/`

```
public function __construct($options = null, $initialize = true, $error_messages = null) {
    $this->response = array();
    $this->options = array(
        'script_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/'.$this->basename($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_NAME')),
        'upload_dir' => 'fotos/',
        'upload_url' => 'fotos/',
```

But the images are not uploaded to the new path.

Answer (score 0):

`fotos/` must be `/fotos/`

Starts with a forward slash and ends with a forward slash.